# Formally prove that $3^ {80} - 2^{20}$ divisible by $5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility

I am not sure how to formally prove that prove that $3^{80} - 2^{20}$ divisible by $5$; any hints would be much appreciated. My initial approach was to write a table with examples that when both $3$ and $2$ at an even exponent their difference is divisible by $5$ while if the exponents are odd, the difference is not divisible by $5$.

Comment: Can you write out the remainder when $3^1, 3^2, 3^3, 3^4, \ldots$ are divided by 5? Hence, formulate a guess for the remainder when $3^{80}$ is divided by 5. Can you prove that guess?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Do you know [Fermat’s Little Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That is a bit too much for a 6th grader I think.

Comment: Well, you're asking for a formal proof, which is a bit too much for a 6th grader...

Comment: @the_one_that_day_dreams That comment raises more questions than it answers.  Are you a 6th grader or are you teaching 6th graders?  Is this for prep for competitions, is it a school problem, or is there some other context for it?

Comment: $3^4-2^2$ has even exponents but is not divisible by $5$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You are right.

Comment: @BrianMoehring It is a competition problem.

Comment: What do you mean with "formally" ? There is no need to formalize this calculation.

Answer (score 3):

A number is divisible by $5$ if the units digit is $0$ or $5$.

$3^1=003$

$3^2=009$

$3^3=027$

$3^4=081$

$3^5=\_\_3$

$3^6=\_\_9$

$3^7=\_\_7$

...

$3^{80}=\_\_1$

Similarly $2^n$ cycles units digits $(2 , 4 , 8 , 6)$ for $n>0$

$6-1 = 5$

Comment: Pretty good solution, and simple to understand for $6^{th}$ grader

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi HARD disagree. This answer doesn't explain WHY the pattern continues. The 6th grader would NOT understand why this number is divisible by 5. The 6th grader would only ASSUME this is why but they would NOT understand whatsoever by this "proof".

Comment: @snared, I agree, I Will not call it a formal proof, or even near to it, Still objective questions like these can be done easily during "COMPETETIONS" using the solution above, Understanding what's happening perhaps will require a little more dive into some other concepts, The simplest I can think of now is binomial theorem , Finding the remainder Of the complete number when divided by 10 will give unit place of the number, And then finding that and applying divisibility will give us the verification required

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi Is it possible to explain it in more details?

Comment: @the_one_that_day_dreams, Do you have a hint of what "binomial theorem" is? Or perhaps pascal triangle? If so I can construct an answer for you

Comment: @Snared: *This answer doesn't explain WHY the pattern continues.* --- Maybe more explanation can be written to convey this, but surely when explaining to a 6th grader (BTW, I don't think I saw exponents formally in school until 7th grade, maybe even 8th grade) it's clear that when a number ends in $3$ and you multiply it by $3,$ the result will end in $9$ -- $3 \times 3$ is $9,$ so write down $9$ in right-most position of 1st multiplication row, then note succeeding rows have $0$'s there that allow the sum of the right-most column numbers to be $9.$ And similarly for the succeeding digits.

Comment: yes, that logic constitutes an actual answer. @DaveL.Renfro without it is nonsense

Comment: A general rule is the units digit of a product of two integers is the units digit of the product of the two units digits in the integers. Thus, $3388832$ times $244887$ has a units digit of $4.$ Using this observation, which is easy to show (by several examples) to a 6th grader (in fact, I'm pretty sure I independently recognized this at least as far back as 4th grade as a fairly obvious fact, this being when for me 2-digit by 3-digit and 3-digit by 3-digit integer multiplication was done), it's easy to get the unit digit patterns for powers of any integer (cycles only have length 1, 2, or 4).

Comment: By the way, the "units digit is units digit times unit digit" explanation assumes one assumes the validity of the standard school multiplication method. Although this can be justified by things like $143 \times 326 = (143 \times 6) + (143 \times 20) + (143 \times 100) = \ldots,$ probably this would be going overboard for a 6th grader, unless he/she is ready for going this deep (and that would mostly likely the case only if the 6th grader independently raises the issue of soundness of the standard school multiplication method).

Answer (score 2):

$3^{80} \mod 5 = 9^{40} \mod 5 = (-1)^{40} \mod 5 = 1 \mod 5$.

$2^{20} \mod 5 = 4^{10} \mod 5 = (-1)^{10} \mod 5 = 1 \mod 5$.

The difference is $0\mod 5$.

Edit:

$m \mod n$ is the remainder of the integer division of $n$ by $m$.

Comment: @Sebastiano thank you, I didn't remember how to format things right.

Comment: Obviously the format was so ugly that it was edited by at least two more experienced people. Thank you both.

Comment: Your answer has no flaws, I Think If The OP is in $6^{th}$ grade, He might as well not know modular arithmetic, Personally, I didn't even knew how to what were the  *mods* before $11^{th}$ grade

Comment: @GyroGearloose You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

That thinking is along the right track, yeah. What you need to do with questions like this is to think in terms of modular arithmetic. Specifically, you want apply three facts: if $a$ is divisible by $5$, then $a\equiv 0 \mod(5)$; if $a\equiv p \mod(5)$ and $b\equiv q \mod(5)$, then $a+b\equiv p+q \mod(5)$; finally, if $a\equiv p\mod(5)$, then $a^k\equiv p^k \mod(5)$.

Now, here's the deal. We first want to find $r$ and $s$ such that $3^r\equiv 2^s\mod(5)$. These are called the multiplicative orders of $2$ and $3$ (modulo $5$) and can be found by multiplying successive numbers of $3$ and $2$ with themselves until the result of each has the same remainder when divided by $5$; spoiler alert, it turns out that $r=s=4$ are these multiplicative orders. That's because $3^4=81$, which obviously has a remainder of $1$; likewise, $2^4=16$, which also has a remainder of $1$.

Now we apply the third fact: if $3^4\equiv 1\mod(5)$, then $(3^4)^k \equiv 1^k \mod(5)$, for all natural values of $k$, and similarly for $2^4$. Of course, $1^k\equiv 1\mod(5)$ (this is true regardless of any nonzero modulus). Now notice that $80=4\times20$ and that $(3^4)^{20} = 3^{80}$. By the fact just established, this means that $3^{80}\equiv 1 \mod(5)$. As mentioned, this also true for $(2^4)^k$; the factorization in this case is $(2^4)^5$.

To recap, we have determined that $3^{80}\equiv 2^{20}\equiv 1\mod(5)$. We now apply the second fact to obtain that $3^{80}-2^{20}\equiv 1-1\equiv 0 \mod(5)$; by the first fact, this means that $3^{80}-2^{20}$ is divisible by $5$. QED.

Answer (score 0):

If you know That $a^n-b^n$ is always divisible by $a-b$, Then the solution is simple

consider number $$3^{80}-2^{20}=3^{80}-(2)^{20}=3^{80}-2^{80}+2^{80}-2^{20}$$

$$=[3^{80}-(-2)^{80}]+[2^{80}-2^{20}]$$

Now first term is of form $a^n-b^n$ where $a=3,b=-2,n=80$ hence $3^{80}-(-2)^{80}$ is divisible by $3-(-2)=5$

now second term is $$[2^{80}-2^{20}]=2^{20}[2^{60}-1]=2^{20}[4^{30}-(-1)^{30}]$$ which is again divisible by $4-(-1)=5$

as both terms are divisible by $5$, Their addition that is required number, is also divisible by $5$

Q.E.D

Comment: even if you don't know that $a^n-b^n$ is always divisible by $a-b$, Here is a hint, Try finding the sum $ a^{n-1}+ba^{n-2}+b^2a^{n-3}+b^3a^{n-4}........b^{n-2}a+b^{n-1}$, Its easy as you probably know sum of a G.P, notice after finding the sum that the sum is an **integer**